# "Unable to locate package" error in Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I activated the Bash shell on Windows 10 (with the new update on Windows 10 which offers a Linux Bash shell).

The installation was a success, but I can't install anything...
When I ran, for example

```
sudo apt-get install cmatrix
```

it returned

```
Unable to locate package cmatrix
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, try running `sudo apt update`. If that doesn't fix it, you might have an improperly configured `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.